# Two-way binding through multiple components

Tags: c#, data-binding, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to bind a model field to a control, I have it working to the form but I'm trying to refactor the components so that I can reused the control and it's attributes throughout the program.

Here are some snippets to try to portray my situation:

Sample Model

```
public class MyModel
{
  public DateTime DateOpened { get; set; }
}
```

Used in MyModelFormBase.cs

```
public class MyModelFormBase : ComponentBase
{
  protected MyModal data = new MyModel();
}
```

Used in MyModelForm.razor

```
<MyForm Model="@data" AddFunction="@InsertMyModel" DataDismiss="MyModelForm">
  <MyDateInput InputId="dateOpened" InputName="Date Opened" @bind-InputValue="@data.DateOpened" />
</MyForm>
```

MyForm.razor, uses blazorstrap

```
<BSForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@AddFunction"
  @ChildContent
  <BSButton Color="Color.Primary" 
            ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" 
            data-dismiss="@DataDismiss">
  Submit</BSButton>
</BSForm>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public Object Model { get; set;}
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback AddFunction { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public string DataDismiss { get; set; }
}
```

MyDateInput.razor, uses blazorstrap

```
<BSFormGroup>
  <BSLabel For="@InputId">@InputName</BSLabel>
  <BSInput InputType="InputType.Date" Id="@InputId" 
            @bind-Value="@InputValue"
            ValidateOnChange="true"
            @onchange="UpdateData"
   />
  <BSFormFeedback For="@(() => InputValue)"/>
</BSFormGroup>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public DateTime InputValue { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<DateTime> InputValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string InputId { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string InputName { get; set; }

    private async Task UpdateData()
    {
        await InputValueChanged.InvokeAsync(InputValue);
    }
}
```

The default data provided by my service is correctly displayed in the control, so it's properly bound downwards, but doesn't propagate any changes back up to the model. :(

The goal is to be able to keep a `MyDateInput` Component that is repeated throughout the application that is bound 2 ways with the model regardless of layers of components it's passed through.
Any ideas?

Comment: [Read the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#cascading-values-and-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite daunting to answer your question with so much code missing or unknown. However, I'll try to provide some assistance with the hope it can help you solve your ailments.

1. This code:

   await InputValueChanged.InvokeAsync(InputValue);

I guess is a callback to update the value of the bound property MyModel.DateOpened , right ? If not it should be doing that. In any case, this property should be annotated with the PropertyAttribute attribute...

This **may** be the reason why two-way data binding is not working.

Note that your MyDateInput componet may also need to receive a ValueExpression value. I can't say that for sure, because not all your code is available, so take  as a word of warning:

```
[Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> ValueExpression { get; set; }
```

I'll put at the end of my answer a small sample to make this clear.

2. Are you sure this is working? The compiler should be barking:

   @bind-Value="@InputValue" ValidateOnChange="true" @onchange="UpdateData"

   telling you that you are using two onchange events. This should be, ordinarily

   value="@InputValue" ValidateOnChange="true" @onchange="UpdateData", but I cannot be certain about it as I don't see how BSInput is implemented...

   3. Note: BSForm is missing a closing tag before @ChildContent

Sample code:

```
RazorInputTextTest.razo
-----------------------


@page  "/RazorInputTextTest"

<span>Name of the category: @category.Name</span>

<EditForm Model="@category">
   <RazorInputText Value="@category.Name" ValueChanged="@OnValueChanged" ValueExpression="@(() => category.Name)" />

</EditForm>


@code{
    private Category category { get; set; } = new Category { ID = "1", Name = "Beverages" };


    private void OnValueChanged(string name)
    {

        category.Name = name;
    }

}


 RazorInputText.razor
 --------------------



<div class="form-group">
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Value"></InputText>
</div>

@code{

    private string _value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (_value != value) {
                _value = value;
                if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
                {
                    ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
                }
            }


        }
    }


    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> ValueExpression { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps...